# use enum display name in @html helper function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

consider enum

> public enum Education
>       {

```
      [Display(Name="display for education 1")]
```

> ```
>     Education1,
>
>     [Display(Name="display for education 2")]
>     Education2,
>
>     [Display(Name="display for education 3")]
>     Education3,         
> }
> ```

Now, I'd like to have a drop down with the above display values

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Education,
    new SelectList(@Enum.GetValues(typeof(Education)))  
    new {@class = "default"}
)
```

I would like to have the **display name** (and currently I get the enum string itself.
Someone knows how can I extract that in the .cshtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this

```
public static string[] GetEnumDisplays(Type type)
    {
        var displays = new List<string>();
        foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
        {
            object[] attr = f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
            if (attr.Length != 0)
            {
                var displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute)attr[0];
                displays.Add(displayAttribute.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                displays.Add(f.Name);
            }
        }

        return displays.ToArray();
    }
```